# Coding Error SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have been working on some code for an introductory python class and I get the EOL while scanning string literal error when I entered the code shown below. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
infile2 = open('nasdaq.txt, 'r')
read_text2 = infile2.read()
words2 = read_text2.split()
lowercase_words = []
for word in words2:
    lowercase_words.append(word.lower())
word_dict = dict()
for term in lowercase_words:
    if term in word_dict:
        word_dict[term] += 1
    else:
        word_dict[term] = 1 
infile2.close
```

Comment: Error comes from the first line.

Comment: You forgot to close the quotes on `'nasdaq.txt` which wshould be `'nasdaq.txt'`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't quoted the text file properly. Something like this will fix it :

```
infile2 = open('nasdaq.txt', 'r')
```